# Wordpress - A partir da segunda página está dando erro 404 - Not Found

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, paginação

Estou criando um tema em Wordpress e chegou o momento de fazer a paginação.

Consegui fazer criar os menus abaixo indicando quantas paginas tem e o próximo e anterior.

Só que ao clicar em próximo ou no número da página que quero ver está retornando o erro 404 Not Found

Na index do meu template, eu defino 1 post por página para teste deste modo:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$post_query = query_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post', 
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
));
// while dos posts
```

E esse aqui, é o código onde crio a paginação que encontra-se no functions.php

```
function paginacao() {
  global $wp_query;
  $big = 999999999;

  echo paginate_links(
    array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
   )
  );
}
```

E, para finalizar, eu chamo a função no template desta maneira:

```
<div class="paginacao">
  <?php paginacao(); ?>
</div>
```

Creio que seja algum problema com o .htaccess, mas não consigo identificar o problema. Já tentei alterar o format para `/page/%#%` ou `/paged/%#%` mas não deu certo.

Comment: Ao invés de editar a pergunta, crie uma nova resposta com o código que você usou para resolver o problema, assim fica catalogado aqui pra quem procurar depois.

Comment: e [não use query_posts](https://naousequeryposts.wordpress.com/) é certeza de dor de cabeça.

Comment: Ok @RicardoMoraleida. Vou alterar a pergunta novamente inserindo a resposta. Valeu pela dica, da resposta e de não usar query_posts

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a dica do Ricardo Moraleida, respondi minha própria pergunta para deixar catalogado e ajudar outros membros, caso precisem.

**Resolução do meu problema**

Consegui resolver retirando o trecho:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$post_query = query_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post', 
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
));
```

E adicionando esse código ao final do functions.php

```
function posts_on_homepage( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '5' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_on_homepage' );
```

E, novamente, obrigado Ricardo pelas dicas